# Timer for Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, timer

I wish to execute a function at an interval of 1 or so minutes. How can I achieve this in Windows Phone 8.
 I am not looking for [background agents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx). The app will be running in the foreground. What are my options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can use the DispatcherTimer Class

```
private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;
    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();

    }

  private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    //do whatever you want to do here
  }
```

Refer: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
public void Start_timer()
{
    DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
    timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(00, 0, 10);
    bool enabled = timer.IsEnabled;
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    //function to execute
}
```

Comment: @Chris Schiffhauer Bro I want this type of work in background.? can you please suggest how to use this in background.?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `ThreadPoolTimer`:

```
TimeSpan period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

ThreadPoolTimer PeriodicTimer = ThreadPoolTimer.CreatePeriodicTimer((source) =>
{
    // TODO: Work

    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
        {
            // UI update               
        });

}, period);
```

Comment: why should I prefer this to simple timer?

Answer (score 1):

One option may be to use [**DispatcherTimer**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx).

Simply register a callback on the Tick event.