# Tracking location in realtime in Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, geolocation, maps, windows-phone-8.1

Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm  a beginner to windows phone 8.1 development.
I am using **MapControl** to display my current location on the map but as I move my position does not get updated automatically in realtime unless I click on a button and re-initialize the position of the pushpin which was earlier created. Is there a better way where this happens in the without the user having to push the button everytime he wants to see his current location.

```
private async Task setMyLocation() 
        {
            try
            {
                var gl = new Geolocator() { DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High };
                Geoposition location = await gl.GetGeopositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
                var pin = new MapIcon()
                {
                    Location = location.Coordinate.Point,
                    Title = "You are here",
                    NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point() { X = 0, Y = 0 },
                };
                myMapView.MapElements.Add(pin);
                await myMapView.TrySetViewAsync(location.Coordinate.Point, 20);
            }
            catch
            {
                myMapView.Center = new Geopoint(App.centerPin);
                myMapView.ZoomLevel = 20;
                Debug.WriteLine("GPS NOT FOUND");
            }
            App.centerPin = myMapView.Center.Position;
        }
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than running a timer and polling, handle the [Geolocator.PositionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.positionchanged.aspx) event. This will fire each time the position changes and will be significantly more efficient.

You can set the [Geolocator.MovementThreshold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.movementthreshold.aspx) property so it will only fire if the user has moved a given distance and not do anything if the user stands in the same place. The threshold you pick will probably depend on how far your map is zoomed in.

Comment: I agree that this is the better approach. OP should follow this one.

Comment: @Rob Caplan - Thank you for providing a more efficient approach.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to put a Timer that requests information from the server at a given interval.

Take a look onto this answer containing a code snippet : [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22012056/timer-for-windows-phone-8)

Comment: That's a bad way to do it!